# finding largest or smallest number out of random list

Tags: python-3.x

I am using this code:

```
import random
for i in range(40):
    x = random.randint(1,500)
    print(x)
min(x)
```

And getting this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-147-bedf53b4ba41> in <module>
      3     x = random.randint(1,500)
      4     print(x)
----> 5 min(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

`random.randint(1,500)` will give integer in between the range 1 and 500.
So, here the `x` of datatype `int`(inside the `for` loop).

You should accumulate the integers(`x`) in an array inside `for` loop and then pass it to `min()` function like below,

```
import random 
arr = []
for i in range(40): 
    x = random.randint(1,500) 
    arr.append(x)
print(arr) 
print(min(arr))
```